# How to delete fields containing certain string or char?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, tr

I have a .txt file that contains

```
Name: Dean AGE: 23 Hometown: Chicago
Name: Mary AGE: 68 hometown: New York
Name: Lisa age: 36 Hometown: Los angeles
Name: Greg Age: 18 hometown: London
```

How would I sed, awk, or tr "Name:", "Age:" and "Hometown:" so the result is:

```
Dean 23 Chicago
Mary 68 New York
Lisa 36 Los angeles
Greg 18 London
```

The only things I can think of is to awk through all the fields and print them out such as:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i !~/:/) {print i,$i}}}'
```

However this gives me the result:

```
Dean 
23 
Chicago
Mary 
68 
New 
York
Lisa 
36 
Los 
angeles
Greg 
18 
London
```

As you can see, it prints out every field on its own line and breaks up New and York, as well as Los and angeles.

The other idea I had was to sed "Name:", "Age:" and "Hometown:" one by one, all with different commands that replace them with nothing, which would work. Ex:

```
sed 's/Name://g'
```

However, is there a way to make it non-case sensitive, as there is "age:", "Age:", and "AGE:"

Comment: Will the file always have name, age and hometown in that order with nothing else before or in between them?

Comment: it will always be in order like that. However there are other elements after the city. i just cut them out for brevity.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU sed, it has an option `I` for case-insensitive match:

```
sed 's/Name://gI;s/Age://gI;s/Hometown://gI' file
```

With a slight change, the awk solution would work:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~/:/) {$i=""}} ; print }' file
```

Comment: Both of these work, except it puts a " " before the names of the people. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Nevermind. I can just sed 's/ //'. But if you have any other ideas, I would love to hear them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wolfclique: Yes, the `sed` command is easy to fix by appending a space to each regex, but it's not as simple in the `awk` case: insert `$0=substr($0,2); gsub("  ", " "); ` before `print`. NOTE: the 1st argument to `gsub` should be _2_ spaces, but to my bafflement this is compressed to _1_ by comment formatting.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F' ?[^ ]+: ' '{print $2, $3, $4}' file
Dean 23 Chicago
Mary 68 New York
Lisa 36 Los angeles
Greg 18 London
```

or in general for any number of fields:

```
$ awk -F' ?[^ ]+: ' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
Dean 23 Chicago
Mary 68 New York
Lisa 36 Los angeles
Greg 18 London
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this gnu-awk command also:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v OFS='\t' -F ' *(Name|AGE|Hometown): *' ' {
      printf $2; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) printf OFS $i; print ""}' file
Dean    23    Chicago
Mary    68    New York
Lisa    36    Los angeles
Greg    18    London
```

Comment: Hmm I corrected it. I think example on [this gnu awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html) was little confusing.

Answer (score 2):

What about deleting all the words ending in `:` from the input and printing what's left?

```
$ awk '{ gsub(/[^ ]+: /, "") }1' data.txt
Dean 23 Chicago
Mary 68 New York
Lisa 36 Los angeles
Greg 18 London
```

**Edit:** And as suggested in the comments, perhaps even more to the point is the `sed` equivalent:

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]+: //g' data.txt   # gnu

sed -E 's/[^ ]+: //g' data.txt   # bsd
```

Comment: Well, sure you COULD do it the easy way if you like... `+1` and an embarrassed emoji if I had one. Would you mind adding the sed equivalent `sed -r 's/[^ ]+: //g' file` just so it's all in one place? (You don't actually need the `:` in the bracket expression).

Answer (score 1):

Piling on the answer, with perl:

To remove the specific labels:

```
perl -pe 's/(?:name|age|hometown): *//ig' file
```

To remove any label:

```
perl -pe 's/\w+:\s*//ig' file
```

`tr` is not the right tool, because it maps *characters*, not words.

Comment: Nicely done; GNU `sed` equivalents are `sed -r 's/(name|age|hometown): *//Ig' file` and `sed -r 's/\w+: *//Ig' file`. Is the only reason for `?:` optimization (avoid a capture group)?